# WPF SqlFunctions - SQLServer

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework-6

Estoy utilizando WPF con C# y el EntityFramework, en BD SqlServer.

Quiero utilizar con linq `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` pero no me lo reconoce. Al parecer funciona con el namespace `System.Data.Objects.SqlClient`, pero al intentar registrarlo, solo me aparece hasta `System.Data`

Alguien podría apoyarme para saber qué me falta?

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Según [esta pagina](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn177217(v%3Dvs.113)), el namespace correcto es `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si estas utilizando `entity framework 6` deberias buscar la funcionalidad bajo el namespace `System.Data.Entity.SqlServer`

[SqlFunctions.StringConvert](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.sqlserver.sqlfunctions.stringconvert?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: Mil gracias, creo esa no la había intentado. Si la reconoció.